# Pinterest url count is failing to return valid response

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I had been using Pinterest social plugin for a while now. I was getting the pin-counts using the following url.

`https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?&url=http://www.google.com`

This used to return a json, which I could parse and get the couts of the url. From last couple of days, this is not working.

Suggestion on why is that so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using a private http proxy server; and it worked fine, not sure what was causing the error. The same url worked with the proxy serever.